# Looping through xpath in Python 2.6

Tags: python, xpath

I am not sure whether i am coding it right but i want to loop a xpath path to get all the values and append it and stop the loop if it does not finds any value.

Below is my python code.

```
def highfailures():
        for i in range(1,15):
                hfc = hf.xpath('//html/body/table//tr/td[1]/table[1]//tr[2]/td[{i}]/font/b/text()')
                items.append(hfc)
        return items
```

Comment: What xml module are you using? Since you don't show your `import` statements it's hard to tell.  If you're using `lxml`, the `xpath` method *returns* a list, so you would iterate over the results of that method (`for element in hf.xpath(...):`)

Comment: I am using lxml module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lxml and requests you could do:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
w_page = requests.get("http://thepageyouwant.com")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
all_links_on_page = tree.xpath("//a/text()")
#iterate over elements
for link in all_links_on_page:
    print link
```